# Given $f(x) =x^4 + 2x^3 + 6x^2 + 8x + 8 $, why is $f(3) = 65$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given
$$f(x) = x^4 + 2x^3 + 6x^2 + 8x + 8 $$
why is
$$f(3) = 65$$

When I replace $x$ by $3$ in the expression I get a much larger number.

I'm doing an exercise in Shaum's *Pre-calculus*. They ask "What is $f(3)$?" and they come up with $65$.

Comment: Where has this come from? Adding context to your question can help people understand why you are asking

Comment: added more detail. It is from my book

Comment: This is clearly false because of $3^4=81>65$

Answer (score 6):

Actually $f(-3)=65$ so it looks like a typo. Of course, nobody other than the author dare say what exactly the error was.

Comment: Thank you, yes it is true! I'm following the Shaum's pre-calculus book and there is a few errors here and there. I am curious, how did you figure out the error? What step did you take to find the correct answer?

Comment: @AlexFortin Missing a sign is a common enough typo. There isn't any analysis or "steps to take" here other than just guessing and trying.

Comment: As Arthur says, I just stared at the the function and spotted the typo. Cannot describe how I got it.

Comment: @AlexFortin As you figured f(3) is much bigger than 65. So, in order to get 65, you need to put a smaller x. And -3 is a good guess. +1 to kavi.

Comment: Okay, very cool. Thank you for the help

Comment: That there must be some typo, is clear. The fact that $f(-3)=65$ gives some chance that this is actually meant , but the error could well be something else.

Comment: @Peter Of course. There is no way anyone can say with 100% accuracy what exactly the author of the book wanted to say.

Comment: Also, it is not obvious that $f(-3)<f(3)$ holds, although it is the case here and actually led to the probable desired equation. The function is not monotonic. The argument with the sign as a common error source convinces me more.

Comment: @Peter I think it's quite immediately obvious that $f(-3)<f(3)$, as switching from $f(3)$ to $f(-3)$ leaves some terms unchanged, and makes some terms smaller, while no terms become bigger.

Comment: @Arthur If we also consider that the absolute value is the same, then the argument is convincing and immediate.